# Nginx backend to one of 4 hosts in Docker Swarm

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-swarm

I've been searching around and haven't found a solution to my situation. I'm running a cluster of 5 machines with Docker Swarm. For right now, I'm trying to get two of the containers communicating with each other. If both containers are running on the same single machine, everything works fine. If one container is on one machine/node, and another container is on a different machine/node, things stop working.

One container is nginx, the other is a front-end nodejs app that nginx will act as a proxy for. nginx "assumes" that the front-end container is running on the localhost only. Although this can be the case, it's not always the case. The front-end container can be running in one of any 5 hosts.

I'm not sure how to get nginx to realize that there are 4 other hosts out there which might have this front-end service it needs to connect with. I do have a DNS on IP 127.0.0.11 (Docker standard embedded DNS server).

Here is an error I see whenever the containers are on different nodes

```
2016/11/01 14:33:41 [error] 8#8: *1 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.255.0.3, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.10.0.2:8079/", host: "cluster3"
```

In this case, cluster3 is the localhost running the nginx container. However, front-end is running on cluster4, which explains why it can't find front-end.

Below is my current nginx.conf file. Is there something I can change here to get this to work right? I was playing around with upstream and resolver but that didn't seem make a difference.

```
worker_processes  5;  ## Default: 1
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
  server { # simple load balancing
    listen          80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass      http://front-end:8079;
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I notice the following gets printed to the kernel logs whenever I point my browser to the nginx instance.

```
[  225.521382] BUG: using smp_processor_id() in preemptible [00000000] code: nginx/3501
[  225.528808] caller is $x+0x5ac/0x828 [ip_vs]
[  225.528820] CPU: 0 PID: 3501 Comm: nginx Not tainted 3.14.79-92 #1
[  225.528825] Call trace:
[  225.528836] [<ffffffc001088e40>] dump_backtrace+0x0/0x128
[  225.528842] [<ffffffc001088f8c>] show_stack+0x24/0x30
[  225.528849] [<ffffffc00188460c>] dump_stack+0x88/0xac
[  225.528858] [<ffffffc0013dcf94>] debug_smp_processor_id+0xe4/0xe8
[  225.528899] [<ffffffbffc1ec8fc>] $x+0x5ac/0x828 [ip_vs]
[  225.528938] [<ffffffbffc1ecbdc>] ip_vs_local_request4+0x2c/0x38 [ip_vs]
[  225.528945] [<ffffffc001789ecc>] nf_iterate+0xc4/0xd8
[  225.528951] [<ffffffc001789f6c>] nf_hook_slow+0x8c/0x138
[  225.528957] [<ffffffc0017994e8>] __ip_local_out+0x90/0xb0
[  225.528963] [<ffffffc001799528>] ip_local_out+0x20/0x48
[  225.528968] [<ffffffc001799848>] ip_queue_xmit+0x118/0x370
[  225.528975] [<ffffffc0017b09d8>] tcp_transmit_skb+0x438/0x8b0
[  225.528980] [<ffffffc0017b231c>] tcp_connect+0x54c/0x638
[  225.528987] [<ffffffc0017b50c8>] tcp_v4_connect+0x258/0x3b8
[  225.528993] [<ffffffc0017cca50>] __inet_stream_connect+0x120/0x358
[  225.528999] [<ffffffc0017cccd0>] inet_stream_connect+0x48/0x68
[  225.529005] [<ffffffc00173bf80>] SyS_connect+0xc0/0xe8
[  269.026442] BUG: using smp_processor_id() in preemptible [00000000] code: nginx/3501
[  269.028592] caller is ip_vs_schedule+0x31c/0x4f8 [ip_vs]
[  269.028600] CPU: 0 PID: 3501 Comm: nginx Not tainted 3.14.79-92 #1
[  269.028604] Call trace:
[  269.028618] [<ffffffc001088e40>] dump_backtrace+0x0/0x128
[  269.028624] [<ffffffc001088f8c>] show_stack+0x24/0x30
[  269.028632] [<ffffffc00188460c>] dump_stack+0x88/0xac
[  269.028641] [<ffffffc0013dcf94>] debug_smp_processor_id+0xe4/0xe8
[  269.028680] [<ffffffbffc1eb2dc>] ip_vs_schedule+0x31c/0x4f8 [ip_vs]
[  269.028719] [<ffffffbffc1fe658>] $x+0x130/0x278 [ip_vs]
[  269.028757] [<ffffffbffc1eca08>] $x+0x6b8/0x828 [ip_vs]
[  269.028795] [<ffffffbffc1ecbdc>] ip_vs_local_request4+0x2c/0x38 [ip_vs]
[  269.028802] [<ffffffc001789ecc>] nf_iterate+0xc4/0xd8
[  269.028807] [<ffffffc001789f6c>] nf_hook_slow+0x8c/0x138
[  269.028814] [<ffffffc0017994e8>] __ip_local_out+0x90/0xb0
[  269.028820] [<ffffffc001799528>] ip_local_out+0x20/0x48
[  269.028825] [<ffffffc001799848>] ip_queue_xmit+0x118/0x370
[  269.028832] [<ffffffc0017b09d8>] tcp_transmit_skb+0x438/0x8b0
[  269.028837] [<ffffffc0017b231c>] tcp_connect+0x54c/0x638
[  269.028844] [<ffffffc0017b50c8>] tcp_v4_connect+0x258/0x3b8
[  269.028850] [<ffffffc0017cca50>] __inet_stream_connect+0x120/0x358
[  269.028855] [<ffffffc0017cccd0>] inet_stream_connect+0x48/0x68
[  269.028862] [<ffffffc00173bf80>] SyS_connect+0xc0/0xe8
```

Comment: Are you using a user defined network with `overlay` driver? if so use `docker network ls` on both hosts with containers on that network and see if the network is created.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a user defined overlay network. Yes, I can see the network on both hosts, I can also do a network inspect and see the containers attached to the network on each host. I'm also able to run nslookup front-end on the nginx container and see an IP address for front-end.

Comment: Probably a bug, Try 1. create another userdefined network and connect services to it, 2. try restart docker engines.

Comment: I just tried resetting everything, include the swarm. You're saying that nginx.conf is good as it is? I also noticed some kernel logs related to nginx. I edited the original post.

Comment: So pinging the other container fails from nginx container? Please try both container name  and ip address.

Comment: a similar (same?) error is mentioned there: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/319223/115690